# Get metadata from FileStream

Tags: c#, image-processing, filestream

everyone! I have a task to get metadata(height, width, size, format) from image, which user was wrote to FileStream. How can I get it using C#, considering that it is forbidden to use any image libraries?
Image formats: png, gif

Comment: "*considering that it is forbidden to use any image libraries*" -- why? Does that include the image libraries built into .NET?

Comment: `it is forbidden to use any image libraries` is it school task? You can read about image formats and create an image format check function using your own code. Images usually has the header that contains metadata you are interested in

Comment: cannot be used System.Drawing and libraries for working with images

Comment: Why not? Those are the best tools to use to solve this problem.

Comment: What _type_ of image? There are dozens of different image formats, all with their own headers specs, that need to be treated differently. You should look those up. And then we're not even going into the mess of little-endian vs big-endian 
 number reading...

Comment: @Nyerguds Hi! Image types: png, gif

Comment: Start by looking up the specifications of these file types, then, so you can parse their headers. And yea, png is big-endian, so unless you bit-shift the values together manually, you'll have to fiddle around a bit to get that working with common read methods.